# Send Data Between Two Form In C# (Dynamically)

Tags: c#, winforms

How do I send data from `Form1` to `Form2` dynamically?

Dynamically means that for example, I have two buttons in `Form1`. When I click `button1`, a label which is on `Form2` will change. And then when I click `button2` in `Form1`, the same label will change again. I need to do it without close `Form1` or `Form2`

For example:
[image]

Comment: Forms are objects like any other.  Any code which has a reference to an object can call methods and properties on that object.  How do these forms relate and what have you tried?

Comment: I need a controller but this controller on form 1. when this controller changed, form 1 will send an information to form2. Also, this information can change every time or every minute.

Comment: @FurkanAydoğan: So... `form2Instance.SomeMethod(someValue);` ?  It's not clear what you've tried or where you're stuck.  Instead of trying to vaguely describe what the code should be doing, create an actual example.  Calling a method on an object is very introductory C#.

Comment: string ab;
            Form1  a = new Form1();
            a.button1.Text = ab ;

Comment: @FurkanAydoğan: And in what way does that not work?  Is `button1` a public property on `Form1`?  Do you ever show `a`?

Comment: its working but not change again when i clicked another button

Comment: @FurkanAydoğan: Then clearly you've made a mistake somewhere in your code.  Code which, by the way, *we can't see*.  Try to understand that we can't see your screen from here.  Show an example of what you're trying *in the question*.  Not just one or two lines of code and then more vague descriptions, but an actual demonstrable example.

Comment: You have *entirely* misunderstood how Stack Overflow works.  You are invited to start here: https://stackoverflow.com/help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharing Data between Forms is not trivial, but possible. Asuming you have Form1 (the receiver) and Form2 (the sender):

1. Modify Form1 to have a public function or property to take in the
   data
2. Have the Form2 instance created by Form1. Hand a reference to Form1 to Form2, using the constructor or some public property on Form1.
3. Have Form2 call the function of Form1 to run the code you want.

Comment: I need a controller but this controller on form 1. when this controller changed, form 1 will send an information to form2. Also, this information can change every time or every minute.  FORM1(SENDER)  FORM2 (RECEIVER)